# Add browser log of selenium as custom column in pytest-csv

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I want to add browser log as a separate columns for all the test in `pytest`.

I am using `pytest-csv` for storing the logs.

My `pytest` fixture is like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def browser(request):
  chrome_options = Options()
  global b
  b = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
  b.implicitly_wait(10)
  yield b
  b.quit()
```

For adding custom column I am adding this function in conftest.py

```
def pytest_csv_register_columns(columns):
   columns['ConsoleOutput'] = b.get_log('browser')
```

But it is showing `NameError: name 'b' is not defined` even though I have made b as global. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixtures are evaluated after the `pytest_csv_register_columns` hook executes, so you can't reference them in the hook. If you need to access fixtures or other `pytest` internals for the column data, pass a function instead. Example from `pytest-csv` [sources](https://github.com/nicoulaj/pytest-csv/blob/master/pytest_csv/_hooks.py#L33):

```
>>> columns['my_simple_column'] = lambda item, report: {'my column': report.nodeid}
```

In your case, this could be implemented as:

```
@pytest.fixture
def browser(request):
    ...


def _output_column_builder(item, report):
    # check if the test case requests the browser fixture
    if "browser" in item.fixturenames:
        # get browser fixture value
        browser_fixture_value = item.funcargs["browser"]
        logs = browser_fixture_value.get_log('browser')
    else:
        logs = []
    return {"chrome_console": logs}


def pytest_csv_register_columns(columns):
   columns["ConsoleOutput"] = _output_column_builder
```

Sample test:

```
def test_yt(browser):
    browser.get('https://www.youtube.com')
```

Running the tests will now record browser logs in JSON format:

```
$ pytest --csv out.csv --csv-columns ConsoleOutput
...
$ cat out.csv
chrome_console
"[{'level': 'WARNING', 'message': 'https://www.youtube.com/ - A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://accounts.google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.', 'source': 'other', 'timestamp': 1586104294304}, ...]"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just want to know whether it is possible to access the variable that is defined inside the test_yt function? I also want that to be in my csv column.

Comment: This is possible by using the `record_property` fixture, the values will be stored in the special `properties` and `properties_as_columns` columns (see also the example at the end of [readme](https://github.com/nicoulaj/pytest-csv/blob/master/README.rst)). Note that `record_property` must be called explicitly as there's no straightforward way of accessing local scope of the test function to store variables implicitly.

Comment: I am not able to figure out to do that. I have asked separate question for this. Can you please help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61073934/add-local-variables-of-test-functions-of-pytest-to-make-a-separate-column-in-pyt

Comment: Is there a way that I can order the columns in output csv as they are passed in --csv-columns flag?