# Add local variables of test functions of pytest to make a separate column in pytest-csv

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to add columns in the logs generated by pytest-csv and fill it using the local variables of my test function.

My test function is something like this:

```
def test_login(browser):
  search_page = SearchPage(browser)
  search_page.load()
  login_success = search_page.login()
  assert login_success=='Proceed'
```

I want to add value of login_success variable in the column.
There is a way to do it using properties and properties_as_columns but I am not able to figure out how to do that. Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `record_property` fixture to store the values:

```
def test_login(record_property, browser):
    search_page = SearchPage(browser)
    search_page.load()
    login_success = search_page.login()
    record_property('status of the login step', login_success)
    record_property('something else', 123)
    assert login_success == 'Proceed'
```

If you now select the `properties` column when running tests, all recorded properties will be persisted there:

```
$ pytest --csv out.csv --csv-columns properties
...

$ cat out.csv 
properties
"something else=123,status of the login step=Proceed"
```

If you select `properties_as_columns`, each recorded name will get a separate column in the csv report:

```
$ pytest --csv out.csv --csv-columns properties_as_columns
...
$ cat out.csv
something else,status of the login step
123,Proceed
```

Comment: I want to make "something else" and "status of the login step" as different column. How to do that?

Comment: Check out the end of the answer, the example with `properties_as_columns` parameter.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Is there a way that I can order the columns in output csv as they are passed in --csv-columns flag?